# SQLite inoperante em programa Python executável criado pelo cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Fiz uma aplicação simples em Python 3.6 e SQLite3.

Quando gero o executável do programa principal pelo cx_Freeze e instalo na máquina que desenvolvi a aplicação (onde estão instalados o Python e o SQLite), a aplicação funciona bem, incluindo, excluindo, consultando e alterando os dados nas bases de dados.

O problema é quando instalo essa aplicação em outro computador que não tem o Python e nem o SQLite instalados. Quando há uma interação com as bases de dados, não retorna erro algum e simplesmente o programa não dá resposta, como se não estivesse acessando as bases.

O que preciso colocar ainda no arquivo setup.py para que a aplicação possa acessar efetivamente as bases SQLite? Tenho que colocar mais algum comando nos programas que acessam as bases?
Para auxiliar, remeto abaixo o programa setup.py e um programa que acessa o SQLite.

Programa setup.py:

```
#setup.py
import os
import sys
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Paulo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Paulo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6"
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
name = "Sistema RMI",
version = "1.0.2",
options = {"build_exe": {
    'packages': ["os","sys","ctypes","time","sqlite3","datetime"],
    'include_files':[r"C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll", 
                     r"C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll", 
                     r"C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\sqlite3.dll"],
    'include_msvcr': True,
}},
executables = [Executable("PgmPrin.py",base="win32GUI")]
)
```

Programa que acessa banco de dados:

```
import sqlite3

class BancoInpcDB():

    def __init__(self):
        self.conexao = sqlite3.connect('bancoInpcDB.db')
        self.createTable()

    def createTable(self):
        c = self.conexao.cursor()

        c.execute("""create table if not exists inpc (
                    anomes integer primary key ,
                    percentual numeric(2,4) not null,
                    validacao char(1) not null)""")

        self.conexao.commit()
        c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

descobri o que estava ocorrendo. Tentei fazer um insert em um dos arquivos SQLite do meus sistema, através do SQLlite Manager do Firefox, e recebi a seguinte mensagem: "NS_ERROR_FILE_READ_ONLY", ou seja, estava faltando autorização como administrador do diretório para poder acessar o aplicativo. Então executei o meu aplicativo como administrador e o sistema passou a funcionar corretamente. 
Dessa forma, não havia problemas com o SQLite e o que faltou foi um pouco mais de experiência no desenvolvimento com o Python para informar na mensagem de erro o real problema que estava ocorrendo com o acesso ao banco de dados.